# Reclaiming accumulated byte buffer Pubilsher

Tags: netty, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

We are migrating to Spring WebFlux (with reactor-netty). Application uses HTTP protocol with Spring controllers. Currently we have a transitional solution which accumulates inbound IO buffers into `CompositeByteBuf` without copying (then it is processed as an `InputStream`). reactor-netty supplies us direct byte buffers. So, it is vital to call `release()` for those buffers. Initially we had code:

```
public static Mono<CompositeByteBuf> collectToComposite(Publisher<DataBuffer> data) {
  return Flux.from(data).reduce(
      EMPTY,
      (CompositeByteBuf acc, DataBuffer buffer) -> {
        ByteBuf byteBuf = toByteBuf(buffer);
        CompositeByteBuf composite = (acc == EMPTY) ? byteBuf.alloc().compositeBuffer(256) : acc;
        composite.addComponent(true, byteBuf);
        return composite;
      }
  ).map(composite -> composite != EMPTY ? composite : createEmptyComposite());
}
```

And releasing was placed after processing resulting composite buffer.

But such approach leads to leak in case when upstream `Publisher` signals error. So, at next attempt we tried to handle error and release buffers with something like this (omitting some corner cases handling):

```
public static Mono<CompositeByteBuf> collectToComposite(Publisher<DataBuffer> data) {
  // such code is not suitable for multiple subscribers
  class CompositeHolder {
    CompositeByteBuf composite;

    void addComponent(ByteBuf component) {
      if (composite == null) {
        composite = component.alloc().compositeBuffer(256);
      }
      composite.addComponent(true, component);
    }
  }
  CompositeHolder holder = new CompositeHolder();
  return Flux.from(data)
      .doOnNext(buffer -> holder.addComponent(toByteBuf(buffer)))
      .doOnError(e -> holder.composite.release())
      .then(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> holder.composite));
}
```

But after that we realized that it is necessary to reclaim buffers on subscription cancellation (which happens when underlying connection is closed). First thought was using `doOnCancel` operator, but in fact there is no guarantee that we cannot have `doOnError` and `doOnCancel` callbacks called for the same request. So, straightforward solution requires us check explicitly that buffers were released before.

Now I am stuck. I have no idea how to handle the case and avoid extra complexity.

Answer (score 0):

`doFinally` is a doOn operator that is called whenever the source errors, completes or the subscription is cancelled. Additionally, it guarantees that the callback is executed only once (in case of error + cancel).

You provide a `Consumer<SignalType>` that is populated with the `SignalType` of what event caused the callback invocation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it can solve a problem. Actually, I did not know that `doFinally` is called exactly once.